# New column as list from other columns, but without nans

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

Basically, I have dataframe like this:

```
  c1   c2    
0  a    x  
1  b  NaN
```

and I want to have column `c` like this:

```
  c1   c2       c
0  a    x  [a, x]
1  b  NaN     [b]
```

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'b'], 'c2': ['x', np.nan]})

df['c'] = df[['c1', 'c2']].values.tolist()
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i is not np.nan])
```

but I suppose something shorter, simpler and more pandonic exists.
Could you help me with one-liner for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with `stack` and `groupby`

```
df['c'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Alternate approach with `list` comprehension

```
df['c'] = [v[pd.notna(v)] for v in df.values]
```

---

```
  c1   c2       c
0  a    x  [a, x]
1  b  NaN     [b]
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like list solution with list comprehension, removing nans is explicit.

Comment: @QuantChristo Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()].tolist(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  c1   c2       c
0  a    x  [a, x]
1  b  NaN     [b]
```